# Stringer tool complains about wrong archive header

Tags: go

I am trying to use go generate/stringer (`golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer`) to generate String() methods on enums. I have problems, which I believe, are because of slightly different format of .a packages on different systems. I have this file:

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
)

//go:generate stringer -type=Foo
type Foo int;

const (
    FooPrime Foo = iota
    FooBis
)

func main() {
    //Just use rand anywhere, otherwise we get a compiler error
    rand.Seed(1)
}
```

Now if I run go generate example.go on my machine everything is all right: foo_string.go is created. However, on a test machine I get:

```
stringer: checking package: example.go:4:2: could not import math/rand (reading export data: /usr/lib64/go/pkg/linux_amd64/math/rand.a: go archive is missing __.PKGDEF)
```

Now, after some digging in the code I think that I get this error, because on my machine rand.a has the following header:

```
!<arch>
__.PKGDEF       0           0     0     644     2051
```

`
while on test machine it has the following header:

```
!<arch>
__.PKGDEF/      0           399   399   100644  2051  

`
```

I think that the crucial difference is slash after PKGDEFF. gcimporter refuses to process .a file, if it doesn't have __.PKGDEF header.

To check this, I edited manually gcimporter/exportdata.go and changed one of the line from this:

```
if name != "__.PKGDEF"
```

to this:

```
if name != "__.PKGDEF" && name != "__.PKGDEF\"
```

After this change (and compiling and installing everything) I was able to run go generate on example.go.

My questions are: why do I get this problem and how do I get rid of it (other then manually editing external library)?

Comment: I misread the path, and didn't realize this was in GOROOT. Can you try to rebuild Go on both systems, or at least make certain they have the exact same Go version? (I assume this is you as well? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/NtepDycHO9Y, though no responses yet)

Comment: Yes, previously I had tried on golang nuts, but no luck, so I wrote on SO. I don't think this is problem with go version. While debugging this problem I updated version of go on remote machine from `1.2` to `1.4.2`. In both cases .a files have _.PKGDEF\ in header, rather then __.PKGDEF.

Comment: The path `/usr/lib64/go` is a little unusual. Is that where GOROOT should be on your system? (also, you shouldn't be setting the GOROOT env variable if you are).

Comment: Yes, on my test machine, GOROOT is in `/usr/lib64/go`. This is openSUSE machine and go was installed there using rpm package. I am not an expert on openSUSE but I think that installation directory (hence GOROOT) is specified by rpm package and not by system admin. Anyway, this strange __.PKGDEF\ header may have something to do with code being specifically compiled for/by openSUSE, because it seems that is just __.PKGDEF everywhere else.

Comment: Friend from the project here. The go package comes from OS distribution repository. The not working one is on openSUSE (we checked it on versions 12.3, 13.1 and 13.2), the good one is on ubuntu. Probably there is some issue in packaging. `go version`, from both OS,  gives the same output: `go version go1.4.2 linux/amd64`

Comment: It looks like openSUSE is doing something different with their build of Go. Unless you want to start troubleshooting their rpm build, I would drop that in favor of the official binary releases (or build from source which is very easy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can see from the spec for openSUSE's packaging they are disabling reinstallation of the standard library at updates. *__.PKGDEF* is a Go specific informational section, and some linker OpenSUSE has used has simply produced incompatible output.

There's nothing you can do except install a healthy Go from the official source.

Comment: There is a [bug now in openSUSE bugzilla](https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=980048), BTW.